# \sexpr returning wrong value of r object

Tags: r, latex, knitr

When I compile my `.rnw` file in RStudio and create a pdf, there are a few wrong inline values in the .tex/.pdf. I tried to create a generic example of the problem, but I can't reproduce it on a new example. So there is something specific about my problem. I'm hoping readers might help me to approach the problem solving process. Nothing I've tried seems to work.

I'll start with my WORKING example because it demonstrates my overall setup:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fullpage,titlepage]{article}

\title{Test}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\maketitle

<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
# set working directory
  wd <- "/Users/ericpgreen/Desktop/test/"
  setwd(wd)

# rnw file saved in "/Users/ericpgreen/Desktop/test/scripts"

# load packages
  require(knitr)  
  require(formatR)
# set chunk options
  opts_knit$set(root.dir = '../') # up one level from scripts folder
@

Create data 

<<data>>=
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(v1 = rnorm(10),
                  v2 = factor(sample(c(0,1), 10, replace=TRUE)),
                  v3 = rnorm(10),
                  v4 = rnorm(10) )
mean.v1 <- mean(dat$v1)
mean.v1
@

mean is equal to \Sexpr{mean.v1}

\end{document}
```

Again, this example works. The mean.v1 object in R equals 0.1322028, and this is the value that appears in the place of \Sexpr{mean.v1} when the document is compiled.

In my case (not shown here), however, the value of the R object does not match the value that \Sexpr{} replaces when the document is compiled. The correct value of the R object `rr.ipt.init` is 1.4.

[image]

However, when the document compiles the following line:

```
A relative risk of \Sexpr{round(rr.ipt.init, digits=2)}
```

I get a value of 1.92.

[image]

Any ideas on where this incorrect value is coming from? I've cleared my cache, cleared the workspace, restarted R, but I can't get the document to compile the correct value for `rr.ipt.init`.

> sessionInfo()
>      R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
>      Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

```
locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] splines   parallel  compiler  grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[11] base     

other attached packages:
[1] survival_2.37-4    reshape2_1.2.2     mice_2.17          nnet_7.3-6         experiment_1.1-1  
[6] boot_1.3-9         compute.es_0.2.1   corpcor_1.6.6      MASS_7.3-26        lme4_0.999999-2   
[11] Matrix_1.0-12      lattice_0.20-15    RColorBrewer_1.0-5 scales_0.2.3       gridExtra_0.9.1   
[16] ggplot2_0.9.3.1    lubridate_1.3.0    data.table_1.8.8   xtable_1.7-1       formatR_0.7       
[21] knitr_1.2          plyr_1.8          

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] colorspace_1.2-2 dichromat_2.0-0  digest_0.6.3     evaluate_0.4.3   gtable_0.1.2     labeling_0.1    
[7] memoise_0.1      munsell_0.4      nlme_3.1-109     proto_0.3-10     rpart_4.1-1      stats4_3.0.1    
[13] stringr_0.6.2    tools_3.0.1
```

Comment: without code to reproduce this "error" we can have many reasons. It will be way simpler if you can give us a reproductible code to reproduce this behavior

Comment: I wish I could. When I try to reproduce the error in a new file, I can't. Seems like there is something specific about my setup. Can you think of any reasons why \Sexpr would not return the same value I see for an object in my workspace?

Comment: It can be related to your code but since is not possible I don't see how to help. Sometimes they are small typo which can sometimes difficult to catch. Try to change the name of the object `rr.ipt.init` to something else to see if it is your code or there's another object with the same name

Comment: I know this is a frustrating way to ask a question. Thanks for the suggestion though. I renamed `rr.ipt.init` in the code chunk to `rr.ipt.init1` and changed \Sexpr{`rr.ipt.init`} to \Sexpr{`rr.ipt.init1`}. Then I ran all of the code chunks in my file and compiled the document. There is still a discrepancy between the value of `rr.ipt.init1` in my R workspace and the value of `rr.ipt.init1` in the compiled document; still 1.4 in R and 1.92 in the compiled document.

Comment: Well I'm not aware of an existing bug which can explain this may be someone else can and meanwhile the only advice I can give you is to re-check your code line by line and start a fresh R session without workspace. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to clear the cache and remove all objects (including hidden objects) from the workspace once again. But this time I also deleted several hidden files that R creates (history and data). When I ran the code chunks again and compiled the document, everything worked. I believe the only new step was deleting the hidden documents.